# Split cell in GridView C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am pulling data from database and showing it in GridView ,

C# code

GridView1.DataSource = ds;

GridView.DataBind();

data coming from database has same name for tow rows in Column1 but column2 and column3 have unique values, it appears in grid view as :

[image]

However i want to display it as :

[image]

Comment: You will have to make nested tables (IMO quite messy).

Comment: please see answer below and accept it if it worked for you @Ankit

Answer (score 2):

You have to use row span to achieve it. It's a merging of row. Not a splitting of row.

Refer following code for it:

```
protected void GridView1_DataBound1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   for (int rowIndex = GridView1.Rows.Count - 2; rowIndex >= 0; rowIndex--)
   {
       GridViewRow gvRow = GridView1.Rows[rowIndex];
       GridViewRow gvPreviousRow = GridView1.Rows[rowIndex + 1];

       for (int cellCount = 0; cellCount < gvRow.Cells.Count; cellCount++)
       {
          if (gvRow.Cells[cellCount].Text == gvPreviousRow.Cells[cellCount].Text)
          {
              if (gvPreviousRow.Cells[cellCount].RowSpan < 2)
              {
                  gvRow.Cells[cellCount].RowSpan = 2;
              }
              else
              {
                  gvRow.Cells[cellCount].RowSpan = gvPreviousRow.Cells[cellCount].RowSpan + 1;
              }

              gvPreviousRow.Cells[cellCount].Visible = false;
          }
       }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to do that but none of them are easy.

What might be the easiest of all:

Turn off top and bottom grid lines in the first column.
Declare a variable at the page level the same type as column1.
Inside gridviewrowdataboundevent compare the value from column1 to the value in the variable. If they not the same, turn on the appropriate grid lines, else leave them off.

This is all pseudo code. You will need to provide the specific details, etc.